# Does MediaElementSource uses less memory than BufferSource in Web Audio API?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I am making a little app that will play audio files (mp3,wav) with the ability to use an equalizer on them (say a regular Audio Player), for this I am using the Web Audio Api.

I manage to get the play part in two ways. Using [decodeAudioData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/decodeAudioData) of [BaseAudioContext](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext)

```
function getData() {
  source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  request.open('GET', 'viper.ogg', true);

  request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';


  request.onload = function() {
    var audioData = request.response;

    audioCtx.decodeAudioData(audioData, function(buffer) {
        source.buffer = buffer;

        source.connect(audioCtx.destination);
        source.loop = true;
      },

      function(e){ console.log("Error with decoding audio data" + e.err); });

  }

  request.send();
}

// wire up buttons to stop and play audio

play.onclick = function() {
  getData();
  source.start(0);
  play.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
}
```

and and much easier way with `Audio()` and [createMediaElementSource()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaElementSource)

```
let audioContainer = new Audio('assets/mp3/pink_noise.wav');
let _sourceNodes = _AudioContext.createMediaElementSource(_audioContainer);
_sourceNodes.connect(_AudioContext.destination);
_audioContainer.play();
```

I think the second one use less memory than `createBufferSource()` because `createBufferSource()` stores the complete audio file in memory. But I am not sure about this I really do not have to much experience with tools like Chrome Dev tools to read it correctly.

Does `createMediaElementSource()` use less memory than `createBufferSource()` ?

**Edit:**
Using Chrome's Task Manager seems like when using `createBufferSource()` just loading the file increases the Memory column something around 40000k against +/-60k with `createMediaElementSource()`, and the Javascript Memory 1000k vs 20k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've found the answer in the task manager.

You need to be aware of a couple of things.

- With a media element, you lose sample-accurate control; this may not be important to you
- You need appropriate access permissions when using a `MediaElementAudioSourceNode`; this may not be a problem if all of your assets are on the same server

Comment: I will eventually use the `BiquadFilter` and the `DynamicsCompressor`. I don't think it needs sample control, don't they? I also want to eventually try to use an external API from providers like Soundcloud or Youtube. I Know that you can plug a Soundcloud track into Web Audio Api... not sure about Youtube.

Comment: Don't know what you're use-case actually is, but it sounds like you don't need sample-accurate start and stop for your sources.

Comment: You need appropriate access permissions for XMLHTTPRequest too, though, so that's not really different.