# How do I dispose a MediaElementAudioSourceNode in WebAudioApi?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I am using `MediaElementAudioSourceNode` to play audio files ([refer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48403472/does-mediaelementsource-uses-less-memory-than-buffersource-in-web-audio-api)) and it works as expected but I have a doubt about on how can I dispose the Node after it has been disconnected.

Currently I have this code:

```
//Do we have already an MediaElementSourceNode ?
if (this._sourceNode) {
    console.warn("THERE IS AUDIO PLAYING!");
    //this._audioContainer.addTextTrack
    // disconnect and remove all references.
    this._audioContainer.pause();
    this._audioContainer = undefined;
    this._sourceNode.disconnect();
    this._sourceNode = undefined;
    console.warn("The _audioContainer was paused and the _sourceNode disconnected");
}

this._audioContainer = new Audio(filePath);

this._audioContainer.oncanplaythrough = () => {
    clearTimeout(securityTimeout);
    console.log(this._audioContainer.readyState);
    console.dir(this._audioContainer);
    this.audioPlayerActive = true;
    // MediaElementSource are ONE TIME ONLY use kind of Node
    this._sourceNode = this._AudioContext.createMediaElementSource(this._audioContainer);
    this._sourceNode.connect(this._EqNode);
    this._audioContainer.play();
    console.log("playAudioFile() END");
};

this._audioContainer.onended = () => {
    console.log("__audioContainer.onended()");
    this._audioContainer = undefined;
    this._sourceNode.disconnect();
    this._sourceNode = undefined;
};
```

Using the [Web Audio inspector on firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Audio_Editor) I can see that every time I run this code (on button click) it creates a new `MediaElementAudioSourceNode` disconnecting the previously created one if detected. Also when the audio ends, it disconnect it. BUT The Nodes are still there even after several minutes:

[image]

I want to prevent a memory leak. How can I dispose them?
Edit:
There is no function available (I think)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't currently any way to do this:  https://github.com/WebAudio/web-audio-api/issues/1202

Comment: But eventually will the Garbage collector dispose them? Is there a way to reuse them with another `Audio()` element? Or should I just change the `src` of the created `Audio()` element?

Comment: If the purpose is just to play audio files, then I think changing `src` is a decent way to do that.